# Display of voice level (dB SPL)

Tags: c#, kinect-sdk

I'm working at an uni speech recognition project in which I would like to print the value of a voice level in dB SPL to improve the application. The project uses Kinect so I have to build it using the Kinect SDK in c#. 
These days I've read a lot about decibels but I'm not sure that I've correctly understand the concept overall. Here I write the concerned part of the code I'm trying at the moment (tell me if you need some infomrmation about the rest of the code)

```
float energy = 0;
rms= 0;
for (int i = 0; i < audioBuffer.Length; i += 4)
{
     float audioSample = BitConverter.ToSingle(audioBuffer, i);
     rms+= audioSample * audioSample;
}

float minvalue_db = (float)(20.0 * Math.Log10(1 / Math.Pow(2, 16)));
float minvalue_byte=(float)((audioBuffer.Length/4)* Math.Pow(10, minvalue_db/10));

energy = (float)(20.0 * Math.Log10(rms/ minvalue_byte));
Console.WriteLine("Energia audio: {0} dB (SPL)\n", energy);
```

In this code I want to do a conversion from the audio stored in byte and the sound pressure level as

rms:minvalue_byte=x:20µPA --> x=(rms*20µPA)/minvalue_byte

and then

energy=20*log10(x/20µPA)

that simplified is

energy=20*log10(rms/minvalue_byte)

I just wanted to know if this makes any sense to you. 
I'm sorry for my english and, If I've written a bad question, please forgive me, but I'm new here. 
I would appreciate any answers that could help me.

Comment: Your `minvalue` calculations have some unnecessary operations, such as taking log base 10 only to immediate use it as a power of 10.  I think you end up with `minvalue_byte = audioBuffer.Length * Math.Pow(2.0f, -34.0f)`

Comment: Thanks! You're right, I don't know how I didn't notice that. I tried your solution and I'm getting better results although I'm still not quite sure my conversion make some sense. However, If you have time, could you please post how you obtained "minvalue_byte = audioBuffer.Length * Math.Pow(2.0f, -34.0f)" ? Because I don't obtain the same line when I do the sobstitution. Thanks again for your time!

Comment: `1 / Math.Pow(2,16)` is `Math.Pow(2, -16)`.  Then you convert from signal level to power by multiplying the log by 20 and dividing by 10, which overall is the same as squaring the quantity, therefore `Math.Pow(2, -32)`.  And the division by 4 contributes another `Math.Pow(2, -2)` for a final result of `audioBuffer.Length * Math.Pow(2.0, -34.0)`

Comment: Thank you very much! I stopped at Math.Pow(2,-32), now it's very clear. However what do you think about the conversion from dbFS to dbSPL? Because It seems correct but I get value too big sometimes